# Show only most viewed post from last 2 days

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do:-**

I am trying to access only `BlogPosts` which are posted in last two days and got most views.

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog_post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=timezone.now)
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='viewed_blog_posts',editable=False)
```

views.py

```
def viewd_post(request):
    d = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=2)
    posts = BlogPost.objects.annotate(total_views=Count('viewers')).filter(date_added__gte=d).order_by('-total_views')

    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'most_views.html', context)
```

**What have i tried :-**

I also tried **annotate** method to get most viewed post, It works perfectly like : it shows most viewed blogpost at top but it shows all the posts which are posted in last two days and got no views.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: In your model, you do not store when the viewers have viewed the post...

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't catch that, `Can you tell me more about what you're saying ?`

Comment: cant you add a filter that view counter is not 0

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, You mean i should do **if viewers.count == 0** then **exclude** ?

Comment: @Smith: where in your model do you store *when* user *A* has viewed post *B*? You only store when the *blog* was added, not when the blog was viewed by a specific user.

Comment: You thus will render posts that are most viewed and posted in the last two days, not viewed the most in the last two days. Since a post can be written two years ago, but all of a sudden receive a lot of views.

Comment: I want to show `posted a post in last two days and got more views` .

Comment: More views means `most viewed blogpost in last two days`.

Comment: @Smith you only have an m2m between `BlogPost` and the user model as `viewers`. Nowhere do you store **when** this viewing happened, so "most viewed blogpost in last two days" cannot be done with your model schema. To store that information see [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, I think you're right, BUT should i make another model of `viewers` and make `m2m` with `BlogPost` ?

Comment: @Smith No as the link to the documentation I added in the comment above shows you should create a model which you will use as the `through` model for your m2m. i.e. the m2m would be between `BlogPost` and the user model but the intermediate / junction table would not be the one automatically made by Django but the one that you will provide. This junction table will have foreign keys to both `BlogPost` and the user model and a datetime field to show when this viewing happened.

Comment: Another model for `views` with `m2m` with BlogPost ?

Comment: You mean i should make another model, which will be `ForeignKey` with `BlogPost` and `m2m` with viewers and `date_added` for views ? Am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude items with no views with:

```
posts = BlogPost.objects.annotate(
    total_views=Count('viewers')
).filter(
    date_added__gte=d, total_views__gt=0
).order_by('-total_views')
```